# How can I connect to sql server from a different domain/network

Tags: connection, remote, sql, ssms

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on 6 machines. They are to be placed in 2 offices, 3 in each.
I created a database instance and I used VB6 and was able to link both perfectly.
I was also able to connect the machines that share the same network using the IP address.
But when I tried to connect machines from the other network, I couldnt.
I turned off the Firewall on all machines, made configurations for TCP/IP on all machines.

How should I connect the machines that are from another network?

Can I use the public IP address?

If so, what should I type in the login form on SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

Is your network using NAT?

goto:

whatismyip.com

does it match:
Start->Run
CMD
ipconfig

Does is the IP address from whatismyip.con and ipconfig match?

If not,  you are using NAT and have to do port forwarding.

If you are using NAT then you might have to port forward on both depending where the NAT is.

Some ISP block certain ports so they could be in the way.

You would have to configure port forwarding on the company and/or ISP firewall/router.

You would forward your database port from your public to your private IP.

Comment: okay so the ip address from cmd is different from my public one.
Seems to be that I am using NAT.
I can access the router firewall settings:
TriggerPort/  Protocol/  PublicPort/  PublicProtocol/  
what values should i add?

FORGOT TO MENTION
SETTINGS TITLES: SpecialApplications/   and VirtualServers/

which should i choose?
THANKS!

Comment: Values I can add are: Lan Ip/  Lan port/  Public Port

Comment: 1433 TCP and 1434 udp.  Trigger on both ports with specified protocols.  Public/Private protocol and ports are the same.  In addition, you **need** to create a firewall rule to only permit connections on these ports from your public IPs.  SQL servers of any kind of favorite hacker material and any public visibility will make your servers a target.  Make sure your SQL servers are secured.